# Run a job in Windows Task Scheduler based on data in a table

Tags: windows-10, teradata, windows-task-scheduler

I have a requirement that a task should run my teradata sql scripts after confirming there is new data in source table(based on current date).

If there is no new data available in the source table, then the task should go to wait state and run every 15 minutes to check new data availability

How do i achieve this using Windows Task scheduler?

I can see windows task scheduler only has time dependency as a trigger

Comment: If you use a PowerShell script to launch your Teradata script, you can either have it sleep and retry or you could add a "run once" trigger to Task Scheduler to launch the job again in 15 minutes. (I'm assuming the Teradata script sets some return code that PowerShell can check to determine whether it's done or needs to run again later.)

Comment: Or you could probably use a BTEQ script that checks for new data, runs the next step if new data exists, exits if not.  Scheduler can just run it every 15 minutes or whatever.

Comment: Might be a use case for a Queue Table, insert a row into the QT after the load and the 2nd process is monitoring it using SELECT AND CONSUME

Comment: Is it wrong to use the time-trigger, like every quarter hour it runs and checks for new data?